# Windows installer (msi) not updating DLLs

Tags: windows, dll, installation, windows-installer, version

I've updated my project with new DLLs. I've updated the Assembly version and the File version of these DLLs to new (higher) values. I've rebuilt the setup project and increased the version of the setup and said yes to changing the Product code. I've added an assembly binding redirect to the app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="LibVlcWrapper" publicKeyToken="F2C6CD8B56B49D4C" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.9" newVersion="2.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
```

.. Yet still when people are installing the update the new DLL isn't being copied over the old DLL. Anyone got any idea why? I keep getting error reports like:

Could not load file or assembly 'Implementation, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be745ff6cbf41b62' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Run the update with verbose logging: `msiexec /i product.msi /l*vx log.txt`. The log will provide the details, and the relevant log entries to your question.

Comment: OK done that, i'm seeing:
"MSI (s) (FC:1C) [13:35:06:947]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\iSpy\iSpy\LibVlcWrapper.dll; Won't Overwrite; Won't patch; Existing file is of an equal version"

... turns out the old dll had already been updated to the same version number - thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that'd i'd already updated the DLL to the same version - doh! Thanks Alexey for pointing out the debug generator.